# StackOverflow code stats

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I often see posts talking about the size of the database but I've never seen any fun facts about the SO code size.  How many lines of code are there?  How big is the folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Benjamin Pollack](http://blog.bitquabit.com/2009/07/01/one-which-i-call-out-hacker-news/):

> StackOverflow’s *.cs, *.sql, *.css, *.js, and *.aspx files come to 2.3 MB.

Assuming an average of 40 characters per line, that's over 60,000 lines of source (probably more, since 40 char/line is generous).

Comment: Thanks for killing my Tumbleweed run.